# File path with space as variable in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have some path with space

```
my_path = "/some/path with/space"
```

I need to pass this path to docker

```
docker run --rm --mount source=$my_path,target=$some_other_path,type=bind
```

And it doesn't work. It says there's no path `/some/path`.
I also tried:

```
my_path = "/some/path\ with/space"
my_path = "'/some/path with/space'"
```

They don't work either

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem with variable assignment, you're doing it correctly. It's how you're using it.

This:

```
my_path = "/some/path with/space"
docker run --rm --mount source=$my_path,target=$some_other_path,type=bind …
```

Will, after substitution, become this:

```
docker run --rm --mount source=/some/path with/space,target=/some/other/path,type=bind …
```

You need to quote the argument to the `docker` command during invocation:

```
docker run --rm --mount "source=$my_path,target=$some_other_path,type=bind" …
```

Alternatively quote just the variable. Bash merges adjacent strings, quoted or not.

```
docker run --rm --mount source="$my_path",target=$some_other_path,type=bind …
```

Comment: Would using parentheses in lieu of quotes also work, or would it still be incorrect after substitution? _(in scripts, I always encompass path variables in parentheses [`$(my_path)`], but didn't know if that would return the correct substitution in this case)_

Comment: @JW0914 That would evaluate `my_path` as a bash command and substitute in its result, without correct quoting. `my_path` is not a variable name but literal command with this syntax. The correct quoting for such substitution would be `"$(my_path)"`, or if you want to evaluate a variable `"$("$my_path")"`.

Comment: @JW0914 There's also the curly braces syntax `${my_path}` which also doesn't affect quoting, but explicitly marks where the variable name ends and literal string begins. It also has some extra features in bash, like specifying default values if the variable is empty.

Comment: I wonder docker itself needs some escaping (e.g. `\040`). The double quote will only make sure it is passed *one* parameter on the shell level.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

docker run --rm --mount source="""$my_path""",target="""$some_other_path""",type=bind

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).